# jars could not be resolved for apache jmter 2.13 with maven

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am trying to run jmeter script using java code. I already made one jmx. Iam using jmeter 2.13 when I tried to run the code it is showing me this error.

> Failed to execute goal on project JmeterJson: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project JmeterJson:JmeterJson:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The
>   following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   commons-math3:commons-math3:jar:3.4.1,
>   commons-pool2:commons-pool2:jar:2.3: Could not find artifact
>   commons-math3:commons-math3:jar:3.4.1 in central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1] [ERROR]

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>JmeterJson</groupId>
  <artifactId>JmeterJson</artifactId>  
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>   
  <packaging>war</packaging>  
  <properties>    
    <spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>     
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version> 
    <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>   
  </properties>  

  <dependencies>    
    <dependency>    
      <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId> 
      <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId> 
      <version>2.13</version>   
    </dependency>
    <dependency>      
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>     
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>     
      <version>${spring.version}</version>   
    </dependency>   
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>  
      <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
      <version>2.13</version>   
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-math3</groupId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
                  <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
                  <groupId>commons-pool2</groupId>
                </exclusion>   
             </exclusions> 
              </dependency>

                 <dependency>      
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>     
             <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>      
             <version>${spring.version}</version>    
             </dependency>  
                 <dependency>     
              <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>    
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>      
               <version>${spring.version}</version>    
              </dependency>  
                 <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->    
              <dependency>      
             <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>    
          <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>     
         <version>1.9.10</version>    
           </dependency>  

            <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>  
           </dependency>  
            </dependencies>   

                 <build>
                <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
                <plugins>
                  <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                      <source>1.8</source>
                      <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                  </plugin>
                   <plugin>
                                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>1.10.1</version>
                                <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                                        <phase>verify</phase>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </execution>
                                </executions>
                            </plugin>
                  <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                  </plugin>
                </plugins>   
  </build> 
</project>
```

Before, when I didn't add jmeter jar, it was working fine.

Comment: Please format property your post...

Comment: how repositories are configured int your settings.xml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit November 2017:

- **Last version 2.5.1 of JMeter Maven Plugin is now compatible with JMeter 3.3, so the most viable fix is to upgrade.**

This is due to an issue in JMeter 2.13 pom which is fixed in nightly build:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57734

Add this into JMeter dependency:

```
<exclusions>
  <exclusion>
    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
    <groupId>commons-math3</groupId>
  </exclusion>
  <exclusion>
    <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
    <groupId>commons-pool2</groupId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

And add:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
   <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: hey,it worked for me..thank you..:)..is it kind of bug??UBIK LOAD PACK

Comment: hi , yes it was a bug in pom, fixed in next jmeter version. If answer is ok you should accept it and upvote si that users know it's tte correct anwser

Comment: Hi @UBIKLOADPACK I made its a question. Please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663577/how-to-resolve-could-not-find-artifact-commons-math3commons-math3jar3-4-1