# How to resolve Could not find artifact commons-math3:commons-math3:jar:3.4.1

Tags: maven, jmeter, dependency-management, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have a project that executes a JMeter tests suite though maven.

I use com.lazerycode.jmeter s jmeter-maven-plugin.

With version 2.0.3 my project runs well. but when I update teh plugins version to 2.1.0 the following error is thrown.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:2.1.0:configure (configure) on project my-regression: Could not find artifact commons-math3:commons-math3:jar:3.4.1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

I know by going through articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363948/jars-could-not-be-resolved-for-apache-jmter-2-13-with-maven), that this can be resolved by excluding the dependencies.

but its just I don't know how to configure that dependency.

I tried the below.

```
<dependencies> 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId> 
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId> 
        <version>3.4.1</version> 
    </dependency> 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>commons-math3</groupId> 
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId> 
        <version>3.4.1</version> 
        <exclusions> 
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>commons-math3</groupId> 
                <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId> 
            </exclusion> 
        </exclusions> 
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

Which didn't work.

Will be glad to provide more info.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268380/how-to-use-perfmon-plugins-with-jmeter-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Use version 2.6.0 of the [plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and add under configuration node:

```
 <excludedArtifacts>
      <exclusion>commons-pool2:commons-pool2</exclusion>
      <exclusion>commons-math3:commons-math3</exclusion>
 </excludedArtifacts>
```